# Which two spacecraft have spent the longest times in libration point orbits? (Lagrange points, Halo, Lissajous, etc.)

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history, record, halo-orbit, lissajous-orbit

Libration point orbit is a general term including halos, Lissajous', and a whole zoo of others associated with Lagrange points in three-body systems.

Which two spacecraft has been in such an orbit the longest?

I specify two because I have a hunch one of the two is SOHO and I'd like to know about another.